# xgboost build error on CentOS 6.8

Tags: c++, gcc, machine-learning, xgboost

Operating System: CentOS 6.8

Compiler: gcc 4.8.2 and g++4.8.2

### Steps to reproduce

Just follow the steps at [installation guide](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html)

My steps

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
git submodule init
git submodule update
cd xgboost
make -j4`

Then I get the error below

`` [root@xxx]# make -j4
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/c_api/c_api.o src/c_api/c_api.cc >build/c_api/c_api.d
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/c_api/c_api_error.o src/c_api/c_api_error.cc >build/c_api/c_api_error.d
g++ -c -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp src/c_api/c_api_error.cc -o build/c_api/c_api_error.o
g++ -c -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp src/learner.cc -o build/learner.o
g++ -c -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp src/logging.cc -o build/logging.o
g++ -c -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp src/c_api/c_api.cc -o build/c_api/c_api.o
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/common/common.o src/common/common.cc >build/common/common.d
g++ -c -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp src/common/common.cc -o build/common/common.o
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/data/data.o src/data/data.cc >build/data/data.d
g++ -c -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp src/data/data.cc -o build/data/data.o
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/data/simple_csr_source.o src/data/simple_csr_source.cc >build/data/simple_csr_source.d
g++ -c -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp src/data/simple_csr_source.cc -o build/data/simple_csr_source.o
/tmp/ccNp7oXM.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccNp7oXM.s:148: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
/tmp/ccNp7oXM.s:1796: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
/tmp/ccNp7oXM.s:4394: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
make: *** [build/data/simple_csr_source.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/tmp/ccnxYuhm.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccnxYuhm.s:44: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
/tmp/ccnxYuhm.s:272: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
/tmp/ccnxYuhm.s:276: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
/tmp/ccnxYuhm.s:316: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
/tmp/ccnxYuhm.s:29012: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 1
/tmp/ccyHo0ol.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccyHo0ol.s:331: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
/tmp/ccyHo0ol.s:386: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
/tmp/ccyHo0ol.s:555: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
/tmp/ccyHo0ol.s:11407: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
/tmp/ccyHo0ol.s:17712: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
make: *** [build/c_api/c_api.o] Error 1
/tmp/cc3gD7Gv.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc3gD7Gv.s:82: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
make: *** [build/data/data.o] Error 1 ``

Is any suggestion for the root cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with xgboost, however from the error it seems obvious that some ASM code is not getting generated properly:

> expecting string instruction after `rep'

The REP keyword prefix in ASM means "repeat this instruction a number of times (defined by the C register)".

However it could also be a problem with your toolchain. Actually, if the code that generates this error is not relying on inline ASM, it would seem likely that this is a toolchain error.

Some versions of binutils consider `rep ret` to be invalid, while it is in fact a valid x86-64 instruction.

Try upgrading to **binutils 2.23.52.0.1**

Comment: Thanks @Eresse. I installed devtoolset-4 and the build error fixed.